# how do i create personal sub domain programmatically with php

Tags: php, subdomain

if I like to create per user sub domain , how technically do I do this ?
for example if  user XXX is registered to my site and I what to associated  him the sub domain http://xxx.mydomain.com/
or http://www.mydomain.com/xxx/
what is the procedure to make it ?

Comment: it cannot be done programmatically. PHP can't tell to a client, what IP address to request. It's also matter of search.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, Yes it can, a wildcard DNS can be setup to catch all subdomains then if handled correctly by the webserver it can be sent to a script.

Comment: @Petah yeah, that's what I am talking about. Handled correctly by DNS and webserver, NOT programmatically by php application, if you read the question correctly. this is serverfault question

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup a wildcard DNS record to catch all subdomains and send them to you web server.

Then you need to setup Apache to catch all named virtual hosts and send it to a directory.

In the directory you would set htaccess to send all requests to one script which would read the sub domain from the server variables and handle it accordingly.

Comment: last one isn't necessary. it's matter of application design, not particular question

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel negative nanny.

Answer (score 0):

If you want mydomain.com/xxx, then that's just a folder. Some hosts will also take mydomain.com/xxx and automatically make xxx.mydomain.com point to it without needing any configuration on your part. Might want to check that this isn't already the case for you.

Answer (score -3):

How would you create the subdomain manually?

Good. Now automate it.

Comment: No need co create subdomains. one record is enough for both dns and a webserver

Comment: how to do that ? can you give some link or something ?

Comment: What you're asking isn't really a programming question. You need to understand how to configure your webserver before you even get to the programming part. I suggest you look for a support website or forum that will be able to assist you with configuration of your particular webserver. Once you understand how to add extra virtualhosts to it you will be on track to automating it with some code.